# Swift ios, sqlite, error 21 Library used incorrectly

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift

I am a beginner in swift language (for IOS) and I am going to use sqlite in my program.
I added the libsqlit3.dylib to my project and used bridging-header. (the wrapper is downloadded from : https://github.com/chrismsimpson/SwiftSQLite)
I have run the following code :

```
    var db = SQLiteDatabase();
    db.open("test.db");
    var statement = SQLiteStatement(database: db);
    var sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT)"

    println("result :  \(statement.prepare(sql))");
```

the result code is 21 which means "Library used incorrectly".
the test.db file doesn't exist and expect it will be created.

I dont know what is the problem! please help me.

Comment: Have you tried creating the test.db-file?

Comment: Also, you can't just enter a file name in `db.open()`, you need to use the application's documents-path.

Comment: Figure out how to get at sqlite3_errmsg.

Comment: Thank you Emil, the problem was the file path. I defined it in the application's documents-path and the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is because of the "test.db" dosent exists.
Now the question is how can I create the "test.db" file. Why the swift dosnt create the database file when the file doesnt exist?

Comment: If you specify a valid path the file will be created if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Thankyou, the problem was that the path is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I intentionally left this part simple, because it's likely people want to have their own logic with regards to CRUD operations around the database file itself.

But, for the sake of completeness I've added some more boilerplate code to take care of this all for you. Please read the README on the github page, but suffice it to say, if you do everything as described, now calling `SQLiteDatabase.sharedInstance` will automagically create a new database if one doesn't exist already. You'd use this as follows:

```
var statement = SQLiteStatement(database: SQLiteDatabase.sharedInstance)
```